# How many indexes can MultiSearcher or ParallelMultiSearch support?

Tags: lucene.net

I was suggested to use ParallelMultiSearch or MultiSearcher for searching when having multiple Lucene.NET indexes. How many indexes can be searched at a time? I asking because I was thinking if it is possixble to search multiple often updated indexes that are stored in memory. I was thinking of 20-30 indexes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I have not personally tried this, I believe that this shouldn't be a problem. I think the only limit that you are going to run into is if the machine your running on has low system resources, but this many indexes still sounds very do-able.